# Integrate Class

Tags: python, class, spyder, nonetype

So I have been trying to create an integrate class for an assignment and while I have gotten a simple skeletal structure for the functions within said class, I keep on getting a `None` result, which really bugs me. The code that I have written down though is written below.
What do I do to make this code work?

```
import math

class Integrator():
    def __init__(self, xMin, xMax, N):
        x = []
        self.xMin = min(x)
        self.xMax = max(x)
        self.N = N
    
    def I(self, x):
        (x**2)*np.exp(-x)*np.sin(x)
        
    def integrate(self):
        y = list(np.arange(self.xMin, self.xMax, self.N))
        tot = 0
        i = 0
        while i < self.xMax:
            tot += y [i]
            i += self.N
        np.sum(tot)*(self.xMax-self.xMin)/self.N

examp = Integrator(1,3,20000)
examp.integrate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `return` statement on the `integrate` and `I` methods. That is why they both exclusively return `None`.

Beyond that, there are some other issues. For example, the `min` and `max` statements here will not work. These operators do not work on an empty sequence (which is what `x` is). Perhaps you meant `self.xMin = xMin`?

```
class Integrator():
    def __init__(self, xMin, xMax, N):
        x = []
        self.xMin = min(x)
        self.xMax = max(x)
```

Beyond that, there are some curiosities with the `integrate` method. For example, the `while` loop will only do one iteration, because `i < self.xMax` (which is 3 in your example), but every iteration `i` gets incremented by `self.N` (which is 20000 in your example).

`np.sum(tot)` is also illogical, as that only works when `tot` is "array-like", but tot is just a float (or int). No need to sum one of those.

Then, `list(np.arange(self.xMin, self.xMax, self.N))` likely does not do what you're expecting. `np.arange` is given a start, stop and *step* parameter. That means that it starts at 1 (`self.xMin`), then sets a step of 20000 (`self.N`), and then because that is larger than stop of 3 (`self.xMax`), it will not include that one. So, `y = [1]`. Maybe you'd want `y = list(np.arange(self.xMin, self.xMax, 1 / self.N))`, so that the step is such that `y` has a length of 40000.

That said, I have no idea what you're expecting to get returned from this method. Perhaps it's along the lines of this though:

```py
import math
import numpy as np

class Integrator():
    def __init__(self, xMin, xMax, N):
        x = []
        self.xMin = xMin
        self.xMax = xMax
        self.N = N
    
    def I(self, x):
        return (x**2)*np.exp(-x)*np.sin(x)
        
    def integrate(self):
        y = list(np.arange(self.xMin, self.xMax, 1 / self.N))
        tot = 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(y):
            tot += y[i]
            i += 1
        return tot*(self.xMax-self.xMin)/self.N

examp = Integrator(1,3,20000)
print(examp.integrate())
```

Which returns `7.999900000008443`.

Comment: I still get a ```None```. It seems like I need to find a way to fill in a sequence within the class, but I do not know where to apply said sequence, because the issue seems to come from the fact that there is no defined range attached to the class, though other sources say that you do that after the definition of the ```class```. I am not sure which explanation is correct.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're referring to, sadly. Perhaps my answer's edit will help?

Comment: Thank you so much! I screwed up there big time!

Comment: Don't stress it :)